# How to set max.poll.records in kafka-node?

Tags: node.js, kafka-consumer-api

please suggest me how I can add max.poll.records in Kafka-node consumer.
I have searched a lot but didn't find any solution for this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put it at the same place you configure your bootstrap servers.